# Copy values from the same row after filtering out a column for unique values?

Tags: excel-formula

Need to copy values from the same row of an excel sheet after filtering out the column for unique values.

```
Date    P.O. #
060719  13
060719  13
060719  13
061519  11
061519  15
061719  16
061719  16
061719  16

Date    P.O. #
        13
        11
        15
        16
```

I used the advanced filter to copy the values from column PO# to copy to another location (below) using the "Unique records only" filter.  I would like the dates to follow.  Anything with the same PO# will be guaranteed to have the same date, for example all PO# 13s will all be 060719, but not the other way around.

Comment: use INDEX/MATCH to return the date

Comment: But why aren't you using the advanced filter to return the date also?

Comment: Can you explain how to use INDEX/MATCH in this situation?  And advanced filter won't work on the date because if you look at PO# 11 and 15, you'll notice they have the same date, so the date will need to appear twice.

Comment: Advanced filter works for me to return just the four records with dates and the po.

Comment: Interesting, I had thought advanced filter only worked on one column, did you have to input anything into "Criteria range"?

Comment: See my answer below to see my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same advance filter to return the dates:

[image]

Comment: That's right. And another option would be to just select the two columns, copy paste if you need to, and remove duplicates.

Comment: Great!  Thank you!